# Vim pasting yank register when opening a new file

Tags: cut-copy-paste

For a few weeks, I have the strangest issue, on a single computer.
On this computer, when I open a file with Vim, the yank register have a low chance of being pasted on the current position of the cursor, with the number "2" after it.

Eg :

myFile.cxx

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <cmath>
```

my yank register

```
irrelevant code
```

myFile.cxx after i open it with `vim myFile.cxx` in xterm.

```
irrelevant cod2
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <cmath>
```

I suspected a bug in my .vimrc configuration so i minimized it, but the bug is still present. Here is my current .vimrc, without any .vim folder present.

```
:syntax on        "Turn on syntax highlighting
:set laststatus=2 "Always show status line
:set tabstop=2    "Number of spaces a TAB in the text stands for
:set shiftwidth=2 "Number of spaces used for each step of (auto)indent
:set hlsearch     "Have vim highlight the target of a search
:set incsearch    "Do incremental searching
:set ruler        "Show the cursor position all the time
:set number       "Show line numbers
"Converting tabs to spaces
:set expandtab
```

The bug appears only after some time of usage after booting and using vim. Once it starts appearing, the chance of seeing it are quite low, but not negligeable, however I have a hard time reproducing it voluntarily.

Comment: what vim version is this? Does it only happen in a certain terminal or in either vim/gvim?

Comment: Also, how are you opening the file? With a command in your terminal? By double-cllicking? Using a Vim command in an existing instance of Vim? If you're using a command, what is the precise command?

Comment: sorry, I'm using vim in terminal, not gvim. The command i use is only : `vim myFile.cxx` without alias defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/74eapd/random_characters_on_startup_with_set/) i was able to fix it by adding

```
 set t_RS=
```

in my `.vimrc`.

The root cause of the problem have not been determined, but it has something to do with vim misinterpreting a terminal answer to one of its request, since the default value :
`t_RS=^[P1$r2 q^[\` was the command doing the yanking.